# Bootstrap Mobile Toggle not working in Django

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Django and I have bootstrap4 loaded with min.css/js files included in my stylesheet references that are properly linked and yet my mobile toggle menu refuses to toggle when clicked.
My browser source shows that it has loaded these files without any errors so I am assuming I am missing a file that is required to use bootstrap toggle menus in Django.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Flash Stacks</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.js' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--NAVIGATION-->
        <header class="main-head">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EXAMPLE APP</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!--COLLAPSIBLE CONTENT-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
                    <!--LINKS-->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href='#'>About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href='#'>Pricing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href='#'>Products</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="page-header container-fluid">
                <h1>Flash Card Stacks</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!--BODY CONTENT -->
        <div class="content container-fluid">
            {% block content%}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <!--FOOTER CONTENT-->
        <div class="footer container-fluid">
            <p>This is the footer of the webpage!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to include `jquery` and `proper` js https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template

Comment: include jquery before bootstrap

Comment: Thought this was included in min.js. Is there a way I can add these as separate modules as I have with css, I can't seem to find these files in the bootstrap4 download.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

first you have to check all html tags and other item;

Comment: add <html> in your page.

Comment: This changes nothing and doesn't answer my question, I have been switching around chunks of code into blocks, but have been reverting trying to get this working.

Comment: have you try it? first

Comment: It was changed not long after I posted this and noticed it. I could load bare JS without html tags at all....